# Append array to already data bound ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

Currently, I have a

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview1"></ListView>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview2"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and on 2 of my button clicks events I publish data to the corresponding ListViews:

Button1 click:

```
List result = GetSomeDate();
ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, result);
listview1.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Button2 click:

```
List result = GetSomeOtherDate();
ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlistrow, result);
listview2.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

I wonder, can I leave only one ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView android:id="@+id/universalListView"></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and append List to it on my events, if the List type is the same?

The only rule is, that List from Button1 click should be always on top, no matter, if Button1 is clicked before or after Button2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest to rephrase your question, because it is not clear

Comment: What exactly you don't understand? Do you have any suggestions how to make my question better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a method like that in your custom adapter : HERE `data` is your list in adapter.

```
   public void addAll(List<mtItems> items) 
   {
        if(item!=null && item.size()>0){
        data.addAll(items);
             notifyDataSetChanged()

        }
    }
```

call this method of adapter whenever you want to add some items in your already populated list. like

```
customAdapter.addAll(myItems);
```

thats all .

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the solution I'm looking for.